# Adding a Trigger to a build configuration in TeamCity using the REST API

Tags: teamcity

I'm trying to use TeamCity's REST API to create a new Build Configuration. To avoid doing everything manually I'm using [TeamCitySharp](https://github.com/stack72/TeamCitySharp).

I was able to create a build configuration, attach it to a template and even set parameters without major issues. But now I'm trying to setup build Triggers and TeamCitySharp requires the raw xml for the trigger configuration? Anyone could point me in the right direction here? Not sure where to start. I've looked over the REST API documentation on the JetBrains site but it doesn't go into the specifics.

An example using the plain REST API would be fine, it doesn't need to be using TeamCitySharp.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain how were able to "create a build configuration, attach it to a template and even set parameters" ? I'm attempting the same but I'm having problems using `client.BuildConfigs.CreateConfiguration()`

Comment: It's been a long time, but I believe it was something like:
`BuildConfig config = client.BuildConfigs.CreateConfiguration("Tests", "Config");`
`client.BuildConfigs.SetBuildTypeTemplate(BuildTypeLocator.WithId(config.Id), BuildTypeLocator.WithId("MyTemplate"));`

Comment: Thanks. Would you by any chance know what method can be used to assign a branch to that buildconfig?

Comment: It's fine. Found it:  `client.BuildConfigs.SetConfigurationParameter(BuildTypeLocator.WithId(config.Id), "Repo-Path", "branchName");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer. I used Postman to do a GET on a BuildType that already had a Trigger configured:

`http://teamcity:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/id20_mybuild`

In the response you get the full config, including the XML for the Trigger. So, using TeamCitySharp, creating a trigger would look like this:

```
string xml = @"<trigger id=""TRIGGER_1"" type=""buildDependencyTrigger"">
                 <properties>
                    <property name=""dependsOn"" value=""id31_MyProject_SomeBuild""/>
                 </properties>
               </trigger>";

client.BuildConfigs.PostRawBuildTrigger(BuildTypeLocator.WithId("NewBuild"), xml);
```